# What's causing this syntax error? oledb INSERT statement

Tags: c#, syntax-error, visual-foxpro

I posted about a different issue I had earlier, and with some help resolved that.

I am now receiving a syntax error centered around the following code:

```
importConnection.Open();
Console.WriteLine("Foxpro connection open");
OleDbCommand deleteOleDbCommand = new OleDbCommand(@"TRUNCATE TABLE CLIENT",
                            importConnection);

Console.WriteLine("writing to table");
Console.ReadKey();
using (OleDbCommand importCommand = new OleDbCommand(
    string.Format("INSERT INTO CLIENT (Title,Fname,Sname)" + "VALUES ({0},{1},{2})",
    exportReader.GetValue(0), exportReader.GetValue(1), exportReader.GetValue(2))))
    importCommand.ExecuteReader();
```

With this being the output:

[Output Text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ea41J.png)

using break points I have determined that the export reader calls are receiving data. I've narrowed it down to an issue with:

```
"VALUES ({0},{1},{2})",
  exportReader.GetValue(0), exportReader.GetValue(1), exportReader.GetValue(2))))
```

I have confirmed that data can be inserted by doing the following:

```
using (OleDbCommand importCommand =
    new OleDbCommand(string.Format(
       "INSERT INTO CLIENT (Title,Fname,Sname)" + "VALUES (Mr,Joshua,Cameron-Mackintosh)",
           importConnection)))
```

This causes no problems, so I know the issue does not lie with the underlying connection or command.

Comment: Take a look at the command that gives an error. You probably have spaces in your input, which causes errors as your values aren't quoted. Also, use parameterized queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Others correctly comment about SQL-Injection, however VFP is less impacted to SQL-Injection, it can be just the same.  Main reason, VFP doesn't really work with multiple queries the same way other sql engines allow by a ";" identifying break between statements.  However, with mismatched quotes, it CAN and WILL break your sql-statements from actually running.

Having said that, VFP OleDb provider does allow parameterizing, but does so without "named" parameters.  It does it with "?" as a place-holder for where the value would be inserted by the .net framework, and you don't have to convert the data type as long as it is in the same expected format (ex: string, numeric, date)

change your OleDbCommand to

```
"INSERT INTO CLIENT (Title, Fname, Sname ) values ( ?, ?, ? )"
```

Then, set your parameters via

```
importCommand.Parameters.Add( "parmForTitle", exportReader.GetValue(0));
importCommand.Parameters.Add( "parmForFName", exportReader.GetValue(1));
importCommand.Parameters.Add( "parmForSName", exportReader.GetValue(2));
```

Also, the parameters must be added in the exact same sequential order as they appear in the query.  So, I prefixed them with "parmFor" to indicate it is the parameter placement for the corresponding field being inserted (or updated, or used in select, insert or delete too).  The command objects work the same for all the commands.  Even if you write a select statement and have values in a WHERE, JOIN or whatever other position.

THEN, ExecuteNonQuery()

Comment: Not properly parameterizing can also just break queries instead of allowing SQL injection, when the input contains single quotes, double quotes or various other characters that should be escaped.

Comment: This is the most complete answer.

Comment: @CodeCaster, I personally have never had an issue parameterizing VFP, or even other databases when dealing with quote values such as names.  the place-holder in VFP is the "?" like an "@someParm" with SQL-Server, or ":someParm" using AdvantageDatabase.  The engine handles the parameter based on the data type.

Comment: DRapp, VFP is also open to injection (but I am not going to arm hackers giving a demo here). You are right it is much more resistant to it but not impenetrable :)

Comment: I'm talking about the scenario where one _doesn't_ use parameterization, but string concatenation, in defense to your first paragraph which could be taken as _"with VFP you don't really need parameterization"_.

Comment: @CodeCaster, so noted... and agree.

Comment: @CetinBasoz, I too agree it can have injection, but much less so.

Comment: Ok guys this and a couple of answers sorted out the issue, but I've got a different one now. New topic?

Parameterizing was the key.

Comment: @JoshuaCameron-Mackintosh, take a look at Help -> Tour for site etiquette, and yes, create a new question once this is completed and resolved.  Check answer if solved, up-check this and any others you find on the site if you find them helpful to your situation so others know what works or was relevant as others look in the future too.

Answer (score 1):

1. It is saying "foxpro connection string" there. If it is done against
   a VFP database, then "Truncate table client" wouldn't work in the
   first place. That command does not exist in VFP. Instead you could
   try using "Delete From Client" which marks the records for deletion.
   Or you can use "zap" command with ExecSript that would correspond to
   "truncate table" but then the connection needs to use the table
   exclusively.
2. You should quote the string values. Better yet, for any SQL operation you should use parameters. When you use parameters, you should do that in a correct way for the connection you use. Here you are using an OLEDB connection, then you should use ? as a parameter place holder.

A revised version of your code would then be:

```
importConnection.Open();
Console.WriteLine("Foxpro connection open");
OleDbCommand deleteOleDbCommand = new OleDbCommand(@"Delete from CLIENT",
                            importConnection);

Console.WriteLine("writing to table");
Console.ReadKey();
using (OleDbCommand importCommand = new OleDbCommand(
    @"INSERT INTO CLIENT (Title,Fname,Sname) VALUES (?,?,?)",
    importConnection))
{
  importCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("title","");
  importCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("fname","");
  importCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("sname","");

  // maybe in a loop here
  importCommand.Parameters["title"].Value = exportReader.GetValue(0);
  importCommand.Parameters["fname"].Value = exportReader.GetValue(1);
  importCommand.Parameters["sname"].Value = exportReader.GetValue(2);

  importCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
  // ...
}
```

PS: You could directly feed the values on the Parameters.AddWithValue instead of creating a separate .Parameters["..."].Value = ... but then you would only be able to do that for a single insertion (not something related to VFP, it is the case for OleDb or Sql or whatever).

Comment: Right I think that sorted it, no more Syntax error.

I am now however getting an "Invalid attempt to read when no data is present" error, however I can confirm I have data in the array being called when it runs, do you think the connection is being dropped by the time it reaches the INSERT?

Comment: Please check your other question, You are using both a reader and an array. This code is partial, probably reader is already at end of file. There I created 2 piece of codes which I think both would work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `ExecuteReader` for an insert statement. Just use `ExecuteNonQuery`.

In your case, if your columns are character typed, you need to use single quotes with them for example;

```
VALUES ('{0}', '{1}', '{2}')
```

Also use white space (*not have to but as a good practice*) before `VALUES` part.

```
"INSERT INTO CLIENT (Title,Fname,Sname)" + " VALUES (Mr,Joshua,Cameron-Mackintosh)",
                                       //  ^^^ here
```

#### But more important;

You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). Prepared statements automatically handle for escape characters for example and this kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: Actually the space isn't required in this specific situation but it is a good habit to get into.

Comment: @juharr Exactly. I was just testing it in my local and I see it works without it as well.

Answer (score 0):

You must give space to your concatenated strings.

```
"INSERT INTO CLIENT (Title,Fname,Sname)" + "[space here]VALUES (Mr,Joshua,Cameron-Mackintosh)"
```

however, it should look like this:

```
"INSERT INTO CLIENT (Title,Fname,Sname) VALUES (?,?,?)"
```

Always make use of parametrized queries. Please refer to:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/neilcar/archive/2008/05/21/sql-injection-mitigation-using-parameterized-queries.aspx

Comment: Spaces do not play a role there, it wouldn't harm having either. Parameter place holders with OLEDB is ?, not @name and OLEDB parameters don't care about names but positions (they are positional parameters). @ would work with access but that is an exception done by MS out of standards (just like access is out of ANSI SQL standards probably).

Comment: @CetinBasoz Thanks for pointing that out! Indeed I have misread it :\