# C# insert into DBF table

Tags: c#, visual-foxpro, dbf

I'm using VS2019, creating a Windows Forms app. Normally I only do updates on DBF files, but this time, I need to INSERT some data.

I already looked at the examples here on SO, MSDN and other sites.

The DBF File 'transport' contains some fields, including transid, a char field with a length of 10.

Here's my snippet:

```
using System.Data.OleDb;

private static readonly string CONNECTION = @"Provider=VFPOLEDB;Data Source=C:\<path_to_existing_dbf-file>";
private void Test()
{
    using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(CONNECTION))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO transport (transid) VALUES (?)", conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@transid", "0123456789");
                new OleDbCommand("set null off", conn).ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
}
```

Has anyone a clue where I have an error?
In Visual FoxPro9.0 I can execute the command without any issue:
SELECT * FROM transport
INSERT INTO transport (transid) values('0123456789').

I have a try-catch around it, don't worry.

My error message:

> Der Befehl enthielt mindestens einen Fehler.
> The command contained at least one error

The stack trace of the exception:

> at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult hr)
> at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS dbParams, Object& executeResult)
> at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object& executeResult)
> at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, Object& executeResult)
> at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
> at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
> at ARKPromot.VFPInteraktion.ErstelleTransportauftrag() in C:<path>\VFPInteraktion.cs:line 252

```
string viewError = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ex);
```

returns:

> {"oledbErrors":[{"Message":"Der Befehl enthielt mindestens einen Fehler.","NativeError":0,"Source":"Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Visual FoxPro","SQLState":""}],"ClassName":"System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException","Message":"Der Befehl enthielt mindestens einen Fehler.","Data":null,"InnerException":null,"HelpURL":null,"StackTraceString":"   bei System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult hr)\r\n   bei System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS dbParams, Object& executeResult)\r\n   bei System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object& executeResult)\r\n   bei System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, Object& executeResult)\r\n   bei System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)\r\n   bei System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()\r\n   bei .ErstelleTransportauftrag(ARKPlatz quelle, String lkeyQuelle, ARKPlatz ziel, String lkeyZiel, String text, Meldung& meldung) in C:\VFPInteraktion.cs:Zeile 254.","RemoteStackTraceString":null,"RemoteStackIndex":0,"ExceptionMethod":"8\nExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling\nSystem.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089\nSystem.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand\nVoid ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(System.Data.OleDb.OleDbHResult)","HResult":-2147217900,"Source":"Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Visual FoxPro","WatsonBuckets":null}

Comment: @Atabai Fekri thanks for the edit, I tried klicking the code buttons but it didn't format it properly.

Comment: Post the *full* exception, nut just parts of it. The error complains that the SQL query is incorrect and probably explains what else is missing.

Comment: The error may be caused by `new OleDbCommand("set null off", conn).ExecuteNonQuery();`

Comment: is transid a string type in your DBF table?

Comment: @panagiotis-kanavos I posted the full stacktrace error I can get. I only edited the input and the path of my class file away.

Comment: @rene it is displayed for me as of type char[10] in Visual FoxPro 9.0 when I look at the table properties.

Comment: Can you instead of `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@transid", "0123456789");` do `cmd.Parameters.Add("0123456789");` because you don't have a named parameter in your sql statement and some ODBC drivers act strange when named parameters are provided.

Comment: @Steve that's only part of the exception. It's not the full message or any possible inner exceptions. When people say to post the full exception, they do mean the full exception.

Comment: @panagiotis-kanavos The set null off command was only meant as a last straw, I deleted it, but the error message still stays. Even if I copy the insert statement with a fixed value into my C# code it still throws this error.

Comment: I'm not a FoxPro expert, but looking at other questions I think you want your parameter name to be `transid` instead of `@transid`.

Comment: @squillman they don't have a named parameter at all in their sql statment, only positional.

Comment: @rene Yeah, I know.  But I see it like that in other foxpro questions.  Just a thought.

Comment: @squillman yeah, that is why I mentioned earlier to get rid of adding that parametername completely. it is a valid thought.

Comment: @panagiotis-kanavos Well my inner exception is null, the Errors object does not contain any more useful information regarding an sql state or native error. The stack trace is already posted. I can't possibly give more information - at least I don't know how.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Please see the comment above, I did the linking wrong, so there were no notifications. I wish I would have more from the exception object to post. But there is no inner exception or any error code that could be useful.

Comment: Check this question and see if it helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35894336 Otherwise, it sounds like there is a field in your table definition that is defined as not-null and must have a value.

Comment: Heh, that's the question I was looking at for syntax with adding a named parameter.

Comment: @MetroSmurf I looked at that thread before, I have no not-null fields in my table. The missing spaces also don't apply here. I tried the .Add and AddWithValue options.

Comment: Does the context under which you are running this have r/w permission to the location with the DBF file ? In C# can you SELECT into a datatable from the DBF succesfully?

Comment: Your code is perfectly valid and the error message doesn't make any sense "considering only this piece of code". However, who built that table? Is that part of a database and have some trigger or checks? Likely the error is stemming from the fact that it has a check or trigger code that contains an unsupported command.
Check the structure details in VFP.

Comment: @Cetin He said that he can do the same insert from the VFP Command Window successfully.

Comment: @AlanB, yes he would be able to do it successfully from VFP but not via VFPOLEDB. There are unsupported commands via VFPOLEDB.

Comment: @Cetin Sorry yes I missed where you said 'unsupported command'.

Comment: As per clarifications on some of the comments:
new OleDbCommand("set null off", conn).ExecuteNonQuery();  
is valid and would prevent errors when no values for fields that don't accept NULL were given (those would be filled with the data type's default value like '', 0, {//} ...
The definition of the parameter and AddWithValue is perfectly valid. The parameters are positional in OLEDB and be it "transId", "@transid", "tid" ... whatever, only helps to the developer. It is used positionally by the OLEDB.

Comment: @AlanB I have no idea if i have to set it manually, I haven't found a special parameter for that in a connection. I can write into the test Northwind table too. But not in this table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it was solved.

It was a very dumb mistake.
I had a **.(dot)** in my directory.

This broke the INSERT and UPDATE query somehow.
But not the SELECT query.
Link to tek-tips, who also helped me and a minimum working example from GriffMG there:
(https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1808490)

Below the minimum working example. Also additionally a field was not nullable, which was found out in that process. Sorry for wasting the time of you all.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;


namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private static readonly string CONNECTION = @"Provider=VFPOLEDB;Data Source=d:\$incoming\finedata\";

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(CONNECTION))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO transport1 (transid) VALUES (?)", conn))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@transid", "0123456789");
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    conn.Close();
                }

        }
    }
}
```